# Disabling Source Artifacts in Rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody

I'm working on a small team of around 10 developers, all using Rhapsody. We've recently noticed source artifacts in some of our classes, which aren't visible in the browser by default. They usually only change the ordering in generated sources, but some override changes to the model. In some cases we've lost time debugging new changes that didn't seem to work, only to discover the changes were being replaced by an implementation in the source artifacts.

Is there a way to disable or avoid generating source artifacts in Rhapsody?

I've seen them generated when saving with the active code view focused, but there may be other ways our team is inadvertently creating them. I checked SO to see if anyone else had a similar issue, and IBM's documentation didn't mention anything about disabling them or what actions implicitly create them. We're using Rhapsody 8.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Source Artifacts in Rhapsody are created to preserve data from the code which is not mapped to UML model element. Such as ordering as you have mentioned, and more. 
In case that you do all your changes from model, and not from code, you can disable the update of the model from code. In the Code menu, select Dynamic Model Code Associativity and then Code Generation. So Roundtrip will not run and update your model with changes from the code. Unless you run it manually from menu.
In case that you do want to update the model with changes from code, but less then the default. You can change the Roundtrip scheme from Respect to Advanced. This will allow you to add/change code elements in the code, but not to; change order, add global comments or pre-processor directives.
There is also Basic scheme which allow you to only modify functions body.
See the property [C/Cpp]_Roundtrip::General::RoundtripScheme